# Auto fill cyclically an array with a list of elements, setting only the first element

Tags: worksheet-function, libreoffice-calc

I have an array of 31 elements in Libreoffice Calc which I have to fill automatically with the days of the week (Mon, Tue, Wed, Thur, Fri, Sat, Sun, Mon, etc...) setting only the first element of the array (ideally with a dropdown menu).

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First place the days of the week in cells **A1** through **A7**.  This is the list we will use for *Data Validation*.  Then put the Data Validation pull-down in cell **B1**.  Pick any day.

In **C1** enter:

```
 =MATCH(B1,A1:A7,0)
```

In **C2** enter:

```
 =IF(C1+1=8,1,C1+1)
```

and copy **C2** downwards.

Finally in **B2** enter:

```
=INDEX(A$1:A$7,C2)
```

and copy downwards:

[image]

***Note:***

- you can pick any value from the pull-down to fill cell **B1** and the rest will increment cyclically downwards
- you can use this trick to propagate any cyclically repeating data. *(like months, etc.)*